# Webstorm, add space to beginning and end of HTML comments

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

Does anyone know how I can change the style of HTML comments in Webstorm?

Atm if I use cmd+/ to comment out a line, I get

```
<!--Message-->
```

How do I add a space to the start and end of 'Message' so that it becomes

```
<!-- Message -->
```

Comment: Doesn't look like its possible. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-141701